# Can i implement Wild card SSL certificate on Two Domains?

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, wildcard

I have Wild Card SSL Certificate and i need to implement it on multiple domains. on first it is being implemented and on second i have to implement. Is it possible that i can implement the same certificate on Two Domains. Domains are hitting the same IP Address, means hosted on same server. But having different Domains first is like: `https://erp.example.com` and Second is `http://app.example.com`. Both application are differently hosted on IIS.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the certificate is a `*.example.com` cert, then yes, you can.  That is, after all, the whole point of a wild card certificate: to support any domain combination of the base domain.

We do it ourselves.

I'm unsure if that is your actual question though.

Comment: Thanks David, could you please provide me the steps to implement that?

Comment: You simply go into the bindings of the app.abc.com website and select https,  select the cert and put in the details as per the erp.abc.com site and its done.

Comment: let me try it.. please wait dude.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled your Wildcard SSL certificate for your domain *.example.com then yes you can secure both subdomains erp (.dot) example.com and app (.dot) example.com.

Below resources will help you to install Wildcard SSL certificate on IIS server very easily:

https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=SO19990
https://www.clickssl.net/blog/how-to-install-wildcard-ssl-certificate-in-iis-7

Answer (score 0):

You are questioning about two domains, but actually you have two sub-domains under single domain and if you already have Wildcard SSL certificate, your all sub-domains will be protected. Wildcard SSL issued on `*.example.com` will automatically secure unlimited number of sub-domains. It does not really matter your sub-domains are hosted on same server or differently, you can secure all with Wildcard Certificate.

What will be secured with single Wildcard SSL;

```
https://app.example.com
https://erp.example.com
https://anything.example.com
```

Ps: Wildcard certificate will help you secure sub-domain only first level.