# Odd SSL certificate issue

Tags: ssl, iis, https, ssl-certificate

So, I have a wildcard SSL cert from Go Daddy, and it has been installed on a few servers. However, on one particular server I cannot seem to get this thing done. Here's the process that has worked on all servers but this one:
1. Create CSR
2. Having gotten the certificate from the provider, I open the MMC certificates snap-in and import the intermediate cert to the intermediate authority store (or personal store, both have been tried). This is successful, in that I can view the certificate from the MMC
3. Go to the IIS server and under Server Certificates, I complete the CSR, point to the provided certificate and it imports into the web server successfully.
4. I go to an individual web site to assign the certificate to the web site under binding. When I select https and the IP address, the drop-down menu activates, but the certificate I just installed is not available for choosing.
5. I go back to the server Certificates, and the cert I just viewed is no longer there.

Go Daddy says to rekey, however, this makes no sense, since immediately prior to this, I installed that same wildcard cert to a different server, and it works fine. Obviously, this is something with IIS or Windows on this particular server.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this without rekeying? Server platform is Windows 2008R2, IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed steps described in https://www.godaddy.com/help/iis-7-install-a-certificate-4801 then from your side it's done. And for more references, you can also check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43247419/7738413

Otherwise, rekeying is the last option.